# How can I import data from .csv to a table which has auto increment column?

Tags: database, csv, vertica

I want to import data from csv  to a table which has auto increment column. But it gives error because the `id` column is auto increment it does not accept. How can I import data to that table?

my table has the columns `id` and `name`

and my **.csv** file is

```
4   jack
10  carl
```

Comment: In your case why would you make the id field an autonumber if its unique for each person... on the other hand you can add the names with their new id's to the table if the ids are not of ur concern...

Comment: it is important to add rows with old id because it should be backup. so i need same id

Comment: then i suggest removing the autonumber on the ID field..

Comment: then can I modify the ID field as autoincrement?

Comment: You will need to reseed the ID with last ID number the autoincrement got to.. not sure if its applicable though..

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use a sequence instead of an identity here. The docs describes the [differences between sequence, auto_increment and identity](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Sequences/UsingNamedSequences.htm).

What is of interest to you, is that you can indeed force a value of a column with a sequence. Of course, be careful yourself to not have duplicate and to set the next value of the sequence afterwards to make sure you will avoid future duplicates.

The simplest example is:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, value VARCHAR(10));
CREATE SEQUENCE seqtest;
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id set default NEXTVAL('seqtest');
```

You can then see that it does what you expect:

```
INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES ('default');
INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (42, 'forced');
select * from test;
 id |  value
----+---------
  1 | default
 42 | forced
```

And to be safe afterwards:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seqtest RESTART WITH 43;
```